# How to copy files in local folder to sftp using pentaho copy file step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have to copy the files in local folder to  sftp location using pentaho.

i have tried with "copy step"step from spoon jobs by providing local path in file/folder source path and sftp details file/folder destination.

while executing i am getting error like "File system exception : could not find file in the files /path".

please let me know how to resolve it.

i did copying files from sftp to local folder using same "copy file" step by proving sftp details in file/folder source path and local path file/folder destination, it is working.

i have defined vfs parameters also in job.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try the "Get file with SFTP" and "Put file with SFTP" entries instead.

Both have support for authentication via username/password or private key.

Answer (score 0):

"copy files" will not be the best option here.
Try using "Get a file with SFTP"